# Why does Float.toString() change the numeric value?

Tags: java

I have a question regarding below code, where if we use the `Float.toString()` method it will do some rounding of digits. Why does it do this? Is there any specific logic behind that?

I have also looked at the internal code of `Float.toString()`. It's calling `FloatingDecimal(f).toJavaFormatString()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {                            
    Float f = Float.intBitsToFloat(1342177280);

    String simpleString = new BigDecimal(f).toPlainString();
    System.out.println("simpleString value  " + simpleString);

    String withToString = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(f)).toPlainString();
    System.out.println("withToString value  " + withToString);
}
```

Output is like this

```
simpleString value  8589934592
withToString value  8589934600  //here value changed
```

Comment: Change Float to Double. I can only guess, that mantissa part is bigger than the precision of Float.

Comment: Simply because Float.toString return this : 8.5899346E9 so the BigDecimal can only use what is left

Comment: Yup, it looks like the precision chosen in the toString implementation of Float,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BigDecimal constructor is simple. Give me a String, I will create a number with it. If you give me a number, I will use his value directly.

Since the String generate in your example looks like `8.5899346E9`, the value in plain number is `8589934600`. If you send the float instance, it will (i guess) works with the bits to recreate the value as precisly as possible.